# Restart app only if there are any changes at all

Tags: c#

I am using some if...else conditions to check some changes in Textboxes in C#. Here is the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUsername.Text != UsernameS)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("settings.json");
        dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        jsonObj["Bots"][0]["Username"] = txtUsername.Text;
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText("settings.json", output);

    }
    if (txtPassword.Text != PasswordS)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("settings.json");
        dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        jsonObj["Bots"][0]["Password"] = txtPassword.Text;
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText("settings.json", output);

    }
    var filename = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);

    // Closes the current process
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Ok, now what I want to do is, I do not want it to restart if there are no changes. Though I also want to fix all changes at the same time.. That is, go through all the if conditions and THEN restart. With my current code, even without any changes the application gets restarted. Please help :)

Comment: Use local variable, call it, hmm, `changes` or whatever. By default it's `false`, if you go inside condition, then it become `true`, check it at the end, if it's true, then save changes and exit. What is the problem? Btw, make reading common (i.e. occurs in any case), having duplicated lines is not nice and you will read whole settings twice, if both textboxes have changed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there were some changes in any one of them using the || operator. If any of those conditions returns true, your code will execute.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUsername.Text != UsernameS)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("settings.json");
        dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        jsonObj["Bots"][0]["Username"] = txtUsername.Text;
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText("settings.json", output);

    }
    if (txtPassword.Text != PasswordS)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("settings.json");
        dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        jsonObj["Bots"][0]["Password"] = txtPassword.Text;
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText("settings.json", output);

    }
    if(txtUsername.Text != UsernameS || txtPassword.Text != PasswordS)
    {
        var filename = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);

        // Closes the current process
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```